# When does the reputation cap timer reset?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-cap

When does reputation cap time reset? Does it reset at specific time of the day? Or is there no timer but instead, the 200 reputation cap with any give 24 hour period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resets at [00:00 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=11&day=30&year=2010&hour=0&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)